# Problem with compiling :

Tags: tikz-pgf, compilation-error

So I have wrote a document which I included some figures, I do my code at overleaf.com then I paste it in my main code :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \filldraw[ultra thin, gray!15!] (1,0) rectangle (2,3)
 \filldraw[ultra thin, gray!15!] (2,0) rectangle (2.9,4)
 \filldraw[ultra thin, gray!15!] (2.9,0) rectangle (4,3.8)
 \filldraw[ultra thin, gray!15!] (4,0) rectangle (5,4.1)
 \draw[black, thin] (1,0) -- (1,3)
 \draw[black, thin] (2,0) -- (2,4)
 \draw[black, thin] (2.9,0) -- (2.9,4)
 \draw[black, thin] (4,0) -- (4,4.1)
  \draw[black, thin] (5,0) -- (5,4.1)
 \draw[black, thick] (1,3)--(2,3) 
 \draw[black, thick] (2,4)--(2.9,4) 
 \draw[black, thick] (2.9,3.8)--(4,3.8)
 \draw[black, thick] (4,4.1) -- (5,4.1)
 \draw[] (1,0) node[below] (x0) {$a$};
 \draw[](5,0) node[below] (x0) {$b$};
 \draw[thick,-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (6,0);
 \draw[thick,-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5.7);
 \node[font=\normalsize] at (3,4.5) {$f(x)$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The tikzpicture is well compiled in overleaf, but in TeXmaker it doesn't
[image]

By the way there's a message error shown as it's shown in the figure, and in TeXmaker all the previous pages are blank, What's the error I've done ?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Each drawing statement in TikZ should end with a semicolon, you have that only for the last five. By the way, the fact that you get errors in Overleaf (red box with a number next to the recompile button) means that it did *not* compile well. The difference with Texmaker is how errors are handled. Overleaf runs past errors and tries to do something useful, while Texmaker probably stopped at the first error.

Comment: your image shows that overleaf is reporting 14 errors

Comment: your code is messy! have a look this `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[ultra thin,gray!15!] 
(1,0) rectangle (2,3)
(2,0) rectangle (2.9,4)
(2.9,0) rectangle (4,3.8)
(4,0) rectangle (5,4.1);`...

Comment: ... `\draw[thin] (1,0) -- (1,3) (2,0) -- (2,4)
(2.9,0) -- (2.9,4) (4,0) -- (4,4.1) (5,0) -- (5,4.1);
\draw[thick] (1,3)--(2,3) (2,4)--(2.9,4) (2.9,3.8)--(4,3.8) (4,4.1) -- (5,4.1);
\path 
(1,0) node[below]{$a$}
(5,0) node[below]{$b$}
(3,4.5) node[font=\normalsize]{$f(x)$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @BlackMild If you add draw=black to the options of the filldraw, you can delete the first \draw (which draws the outlines for the rectangles).

Comment: As @TorbjørnT. said, `\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=gray!15] 
(1,0) rectangle +(1,3)
(2,0) rectangle +(1,4)
(3,0) rectangle +(1,3.8)
(4,0) rectangle +(1,4.1);
\path 
(1,0) node[below]{$a$}
(5,0) node[below]{$b$}
(3,4.5) node[font=\normalsize]{$f(x)$};
\draw[-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
`